How can you think clearly and find what you really want?
Well, I want to told you a thought of mine. I did a thought experiment (last week) and imagined my self to go five years ago and be trapped into the past-self ,but keep in mind that my brain will preserve the experience, the maturity and the thinking strategies that I have developed today.
So I imagined that then I will have the confidence and the wisdom to move forward. I would be much more wise ,dedicated and focused in my studies, goals and I would stand out. So thinking it backwards ,I am now sceptical what things I must think of in order to find my purpose in life and my focus, what my future five years ahead self would know that I do not, what tips my future self would give.
How can I actually find the things that make me happy and identify those that are byproduct of my social life, which I do not really want? I ask this question because I think compared my current self with the past, I have overcame some difficulties and now I have some answers that if I knew I would be happy and successful .
How can throw away my everyday desires that are fake?  Any thoughts?

This is a complex question and wisdom traditions around the world would have very different answers, from transcendental meditation to the careful study of philosophy itself

if you have any thought or subjective opinion I would be really intersted  to hear...

You can only do the best you can. There is a meaning of the word folly which means you are bound to make poor decisions, and later realise there may have been a better path, if you had known more, or thought more, or had better advice. No blame. It's only by making mistakes that you understand why things should be done, or are like they are, otherwise you are blindly following 'received wisdom' without knowing the reasons behind it.

Certainly, the only way to learn and grow is by taking action and doing mistakes. But I think that there is a debatable answer to my thought experiment. An answer might be to follow my values and act according to them ,but will I be really happy afterwards. Perhaps, in the end I will feel that I have not let my self to be free.

You may try interacting with the ChatGPT personas I created for this sort of debate, https://www.apronus.com

"How do you get to Carnegie Hall?"


How can I actually find the things that make me happy and identify those that are byproduct of my social life, which I do not really want?

Many toddlers and puppies express a quality that I regard as the greatest good in life: unreasonable happiness! The unreasonable happiness is experienced within and must be an inherent property of social relations and yet the patterns of drama in society can become a source of unhappiness. If a pattern of drama makes you unhappy then either you must avoid that pattern, or you will unconsciously fail in the roles that fail to make you happy, or you might make efforts to transform your drama so the social patterns no longer draw down your capacity for unreasonable happiness. This means introspecting how the drama of life interacts with your happiness or unhappiness as you try to become prudent in the world, that is, as you try to govern your actions by the use of reason notice how the patterns of drama influence your moods.

There is so much old wisdom on this topic.  If you would desire to learn about going beyond desire. . . How does desire differ from will?  Will can will without deliberate thought.  Without thought desire is overcome.  What is this nonsense?  Consider "All is vanity."  It's a sobering start; possibly a non-sequitur.

Well, I see that there is a thought here. But, I strongly disagree with your last-punch line. I am not a philosophy guy but why someone can say that all is vanity? And if it is true why do we wake up every morning? Anyways I have realised that the initial question is indeed complex and to a certain degree subjective. But I want to hear some personal insights ,rather than philosophical complex and ambiguous answears

"Better never to begin. Once begun, better to finish."

@Konstantinos "All is vanity" serves as an antidote sentiment to the problem of being carried away by worldly desire. I don't mean to rain on worldly wonders but sometimes one can take it or leave it.  Initially it's a rationalisation, then not even that.  Practical necessity moves to the fore.

Buddha had an amusingly dour piece of advice for Girimananda to help him go beyond.

Heidegger refers to "The inventive thinking of beyng [which] does indeed not simply think up a concept; instead, it gains that liberation from mere beings which makes appropriate the determination of thinking on the basis of beyng. ..." (Contributions to Philosophy, §265)

What is this view from beyond? and is it worth comprehending?

I would say the same as Joseph Weissman's comment:

Philosophy-study + Sitting-meditation

Except that it is important to understand that the two are one!
Think of a beginning physics student asking whether physics-theory (classwork) or the practicals (lab-work) is physics.
Clearly both are physics, both are often even "the same physics" but seen through different lenses.
Likewise here:

philosophy-study is the theory
sitting-meditation is the practicals

You learn the broad contours of what you are studying by reading; you confirm or refute what "the greats" say in "your own lab".
Its really the heart of traditional philosophy. The god at Delphi who pronounced Socrates the wisest man had the inscription Know Thyself or in Greek
Gnothi — seauton

"Know then thyself, presume not God to scan;
The proper study of mankind is man."

Alexander Pope, An Essay on Man: Epistle II, 1733


I think philosophy is not helpful . While philosophers have provided valuable insights (that are just nice) into these topics, finding purpose and clarity in life remains a deeply personal and ongoing journey (but the most of us want to succeed, be happy and know what they are doing. And when you start question your purpose, you are not sure what actually want. Ο!! Τhis is frightening.). Philosophical ideas can offer tools and frameworks for this exploration, but ultimately, individuals must navigate these questions for themselves, drawing on philosophy as one resource among many (just crazy)

@Konstantinos its true the amount of garbage philosophy is very great. But if you stick to few like  Socrates, Marcus Aurelius, Spinoza you will see they are genuine and helpful. Also see my other answer

I really wonder how many intelligent people just know what they want to do. For example, Albert Einstein from his early age knew that physics and math were his things that he had to devote his life. Do not forget Magnus Carlsen , when he learned about chess he instantly fell in love .Some athletes Kobe Bryant , Vasilly Lomancheko (from young age were sure about their passion). The list goes on and on. How they knew. Perhaps, they do it without thinking too much...

That comes (or at least helped) by meditation. And its not as simplistic as you make out.  Beethoven had no idea he had to be a musician. Instead he had a very cruel father who would trash him as a young boy and make him practice. I believe Michael Jackson's case is analogous
